# Why does VIM do not indent two line for-loop properly?

Tags: c, vim, editor, vi

I entered the following code in VIM, why does it do not indenting properly ? Here I wanna repeat the same loop 3 times, they are not nested loops. This code is just do describe my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c)
    printf("%d\t%c\n", c, c);
    for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c)
      printf("%d\t%c\n", c, c);
      for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c)
        printf("%d\t%c\n"; c, c)
  return 0;
}
```

This is my `.vimrc` configuration

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

Is anything wrong in this settings ?

The same code in `emacs` looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c)
    printf("%d\t%c", c, c);
  for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c)
    printf("%d\t%c", c, c);
  for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c)
    printf("%d\t%c", c, c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try turning off smartindent. It can interfere with file-based indenting and Vim has C-file-based-indenting built-in.

Comment: @paxdiablo Its not working..

Comment: Hence the "try" and why it was a comment rather than an answer. You'll have to wait for someone more knowledgeable, I guess.

Comment: i would suggest you to use emacs,its outstanding and it supports indentation very well.

Comment: Did you try my answer? (adding `filetype plugin indent on` to your vimrc)

Comment: you mean adding `c plugin indent on` ? its not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c) {
    printf("%d\t%c\n", c, c);
    for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c) {
      printf("%d\t%c\n", c, c);
      for (c = 0; c < 100; ++c) {
        printf("%d\t%c\n"; c, c)
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can indent your `#include` by four spaces to format it correctly. ;]

Comment: they are not nested loops. I just wanna repeat the same loop three times. I have made an edit to the question .

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your vimrc. This will enable filetype plugins and get the indentation you want.

```
 filetype plugin indent on
```

According to [`:h smartindent`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27smartindent%27). Smart indent will only insert tabs unless you put curly brackets in.

```
Normally 'autoindent' should also be on when using 'smartindent'.
An indent is automatically inserted:
- After a line ending in '{'.
- After a line starting with a keyword from 'cinwords'.
- Before a line starting with '}' (only with the "O" command).
When typing '}' as the first character in a new line, that line is
given the same indent as the matching '{'.
```